# webpage is not centered in tablet

Tags: html, css, tablet

I developing a webpage in django and now i came to test it in all devices. page is running well in all major pc webbrowsers.

this is my page: http://locateyourdate.de/

but if you open the page in tablet pc, the whole page's align goes to left, and not like how it looks in normal pc webbrowser which is centered

how can i fix it? i tried with position absolute but i destroyed the page, I am really stuck how to make it work

Comment: Which tablet browser are you seeing the problem in?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: [55 Errors, 5 warning(s)](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocateyourdate.de%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding the errors Quentin mentioned, if your tablet has a max-width resolution of 1024px like most tablets, it's understandable why the site appears aligned to the left. The main container is simply larger than 1024px.

If you want your site to look good on tablets and smaller devices, it needs to be responsive.
Google for 'responsive web design'.

Comment: Without meta viewport, most tablets will tell the world they're >960px wide and "zoom out" to display the page as on a 1024px monitor. @Jacob question is still unanswered.

Comment: @FelipeAls, so i should set meta tag viewport?